# Used dd to write userdata.img into phone, now asking me for password

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, locked-out, password-protection

I used `dd` from twrp terminal to write to userdata on my phone using `dd if=userdata.img of=/dev/block/platform/mtk-msdc.0/by-name/userdata` when I did reboot, it asks for my password. I tried all the previous passwords I used before, but to no veil. Why is it asking for my password? How to overcome this situtation? Reseting does not seem to be working.

Comment: Because of the encryption, encrypted backups are bound to the device. Have you performed a factory reset after you have created the backup?

Comment: If by "resetting" you mean "performing a factory reset" – then no, that just destroyed your last chance to access and decrypt those data, as a factory reset also destroys the key file needed for decryption.

Comment: But I never encrypted my device in the first place to begin with. Yes I did a factory reset, will flashing userdata.img again could work?

Comment: If this phone is dead my mum's gonna kill me

Comment: Good news!!! I reflashed userdata.img with dd from twrp terminal and I'm in the phone yes!!!

Comment: It didn't ask for a password this time.